# How can I extract the field names from a Python (legacy) format string?

Tags: python, regex, string, string-formatting

I'm finding this to be a difficult question to put into words, hence the examples. However, I'm basically being given [arbitrary format strings](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), and I need to go (efficiently) fetch the appropriate values from a database, in order to build a relevant mapping object dynamically.

Given a format string expecting a mapping object, e.g.:

```
>>> 'Hello, %(first-name)s!' % {'first-name': 'Dolph'}
'Hello, Dolph!'
```

I'm looking for an implementation of 'infer_field_names()' below:

```
>>> infer_field_names('Hello, %(first-name)s! You are #%(customer-number)d.')
['first-name', 'customer-number']
```

I know I could write regex (or even try to parse exception messages!), but I'm hoping there's an existing API call I can use instead..?

Based on the [string Formatter docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html), I thought this would work:

```
>>> import string
>>> format_string = 'Hello, %(first-name)s! You are #%(customer-number)d.'
>>> [x[1] for x in string.Formatter().parse(format_string)]
[None]
```

But that doesn't quite return what I would expect (a list of `field_name`s, per the docs).

Comment: Note that your method works, but only for `{}`-style formatting: `'Hello, {first-name}s! You are #{customer-number}d.'`

Comment: @beerbajay: Tested that ^, and you're right... I suppose it's not too late to change styles. Why does it work for one style and not another? Any docs on that?

Comment: Because `string.Formatter` was implemented later (after [PEP-3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using the `%` operator to format strings, the right operand doesn't have to be a dictionary -- it only has to be some object mapping the required field names to the values that are supposed to be substistuted.  So all you need to do is write a class with an redefined `__getitem__()` that retrieves the values from the database.

Here's a pointless example:

```
class Mapper(object):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return item   

print 'Hello, %(first-name)s!' % Mapper()
```

prints

```
Hello, first-name!
```

Comment: I need to retrieve all the values in a single query, but this is really cool and I can work with it :)

Comment: You can do fetch all of them in this way, just write your `Mapper` so that it saves each `item` to an internal cache and read out all the values after you run the formatting operation. e.g. instead of `return item`, do `self.items.append(item)` on an internal `items` list.

Comment: @Dolph: You can of course use this to collect the names of the needed items, build the dictionary and do the actual formatting in a second % operation.  (Probably this is what you mean by "I can work with it".)

Comment: @beerbajay, Sven: that's exactly what I did